# how to install devstack on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation, openstack

I am new to ubuntu and i have to install devstack when I am trying to install it gives the following error message.

```
[ERROR] /home/tcs2/devstack/functions-common:607 git call failed:
[git clone git://git.openstack.org/openstack/requirements.git /opt/stack/requirements]
Error on exit
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2016-01-21-082913.txt for details
/bin/sh: 1: brctl: not found
sudo: ebtables: command not found
sudo: ebtables: command not found    
sudo: ebtables: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this command work in your machine?

```
git clone git://git.openstack.org/openstack/requirements.git /opt/stack/requirements
```

If you have new (relatively fast) machine, you could try with **BOMSI**. It's much more simple, and you can install everything with a single click. It does it a while to install everything do.

This will get you a 3 node set up with Kilo:

```
git clone https://github.com/julenl/BOMSI.git
cd BOMSI/CentOS7-Kilo/
for NODE in controller compute1 network; do ./bomsi-iso.sh -n=$NODE; done
```

Or if you prefer a GUI:

```
git clone https://github.com/julenl/BOMSI.git
cd BOMSI/CentOS7-Kilo/ 
./bomsi_gui.py
```

... and click on "Local KVM" (make sure 3_nodes is selected).

Comment: The command first mentioned in the answer doesnt work in my system.it gives following error message....tcs1@tcs1:~$ git clone git://git.openstack.org/openstack/requirements.git /opt/stack/requirements
Cloning into '/opt/stack/requirements'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.openstack.org:
git.openstack.org: Name or service not known

tcs1@tcs1:~$

Comment: Is your internet connection working properly? try "ping git.openstack.org"

Comment: sir my internet connection has  proxy is it the reason for not installing devstack?

Comment: Well.. you need to download the stuff from somewhere... So, the ping to the git repository doesn't work?